editbin: fatal error LNK1342: failed to save a backup copy of the binary file to be edited
I've gotten error code LNK1342 from editbin but cannot find this documented anywhere. What does it mean?
The command I ran and its results were:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86\editbin.exe" /LARGEADDRESSAWARE C:\working\source\blk\Build\..\Bin\blk.exe
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Editor Version 14.29.30133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Result:
C:\working\source\blk\Build\..\Bin\blk.exe : fatal error LNK1342: failed to save a backup copy of the binary file to be edited
Maybe there is something wrong with the EXE I am targeting, since the same command has worked successfully in the past?

This error is not listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-errors-and-warnings.
At time of writing the StackOverflow search finds zero results for this error. Google search for site:stackoverflow.com lnk1342 returns two links which actually do not mention the error.

After some trial and error it turns out that this message can be displayed when the target path or filename is wrong.
So essentially it just means "file not found".
